# Passing in Array of Vec3 using vispy's gloo

Tags: python, opengl, shader

So I'm using the gloo package in python to run some basic GL shaders.

For one shader, I need to pass in a uniform that is an array of 10 vec3s:

```
uniform vec3 u_warps[10];
```

However, when I try to set a value of this in python:

```
program['u_warps'] = warps // or gloo.VertexBuffer(warps)
```

I get the error:

> KeyError: 'Unknown uniform or attribute u_warp'

Which suggests to me that this library is doesn't recognize array uniforms? If I remove the brackets after 'warps' ("warps[10] -> warps"), then the uniform is found, but fails to set correctly (because I am passing in an array worth of data).

Is there something I'm missing? Does anyone know if there is a way to set array uniforms in gloo?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I emailed the people that maintain vispy and got the answer:

"For now the only solution is to pass in the elements of the uniform array individually:"

```
program['u_warps[0]'] = warps[0]
program['u_warps[1]'] = warps[1]
...
```

The maintainers said they hope to fix this issue soon.